# constraintset. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x3

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to use ConstraintSet.load (Context context, int resourceId) in my project. It works fine with api 19 and up, but causes error when tested with api 16.

I have tried replacing the dimensions with actual value (56dp, -1dp) and values in dimens resource file but always gives the java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x3 error.

Here is the xml file: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuWY8.png)

Here is the main activity: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Mwp.png)

and this is the error:

07-08 13:51:02.730 14466-14466/help.logs.error.constrainterror E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{help.logs.error.constrainterror/help.logs.error.constrainterror.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x3
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x3
                                                                                 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:463)
                                                                                 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet.populateConstraint(ConstraintSet.java:2040)
                                                                                 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet.fillFromAttributeList(ConstraintSet.java:1901)
                                                                                 at android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet.load(ConstraintSet.java:1870)
                                                                                 at help.logs.error.constrainterror.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

Answer (score 1):

I have not found the answer to the question yet but using "mConstraint.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main_second);" instead of "mConstraint.load()" as a work around did the trick.